# Get folder where Webi report is stored in FRS

Tags: webi, business-objects-sdk

I have a report on Webi server. I need a code snippet to show the folder where the report is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing needed is a IInfoObject for the WebI report you are looking for.  After that is is a couple of queries against the IInfoStore looping through the SI_PARENTID values you get back.

```
IInfoObject myReport; // the WebI report you are trying to find the folder it is in
IInfoStore infoStore; // your gateway to the CMS database

// I'm not sure what info is in your myReport IInfoObject, so make sure we have what is needed
String infoStoreQuery = "select SI_ID,SI_NAME,SI_PARENTID from CI_INFOOBJECTS where SI_ID="+myReport.getID();
IInfoObjects infoObjects = infoStore.query(infoStoreQuery);

// because I used the ID there should be only 1 object in the infoObjects
IInfoObject myReportWithParentFolder = (IInfoObject)infoObjects.get(0);
int parentFolderId = myReportWithParentFolder.getParentID(); // ID of the folder that contains the report

// BEGIN now loop through the folders going backwards to get full path to the report
// loop not shown
infoStoreQuery = "select SI_ID,SI_NAME,SI_PARENTID from CI_INFOOBJECTS where SI_ID="+parentFolderId ;
infoObjects = infoStore.query(infoStoreQuery);
IInfoObject folder = (IInfoObject)infoObjects.get(0);
String folderName = folder.getTitle();
int parentFolderId = folder.getParentID(); 
// END loop area
```